# Как добавлять строчки в одну колонку по очереди?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Мне нужно добавить количество секунд с определенного момента времени до текущего  в колонку. У меня получилось добавить все значения только в один момент времени и они получились одинаковые. Как сделать, чтобы они добавлялись с промежутком в 1 секунду?
Запрос:

```
update "Client" 
set id = (((DATE_PART('day', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - '1900-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp with time zone)*24 + DATE_PART('hour', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - '1900-01-01 00:00:05'::timestamp ))  * 60) +  ((DATE_PART('minute', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - '1900-01-01 00:00:07'::timestamp))* 60)+ 
DATE_PART('minute',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  - '1900-01-01 00:00:09' ::timestamp));
commit;
```

То, что получилось:

[image: То что получилось]

Должны получится все значения разные.

Comment: А где у вас условие в запросе по которому БД должна определить в какую строку писать информацию? Сейчас у вас меняются все строки одним запросом, без условия.

Comment: Добавить в источник данных запроса SEQUENCE и плюсовать его значение. Ну или тупо прибавлять ROW_ID().

Comment: не особо понятно, что нужно... не помешал бы пример данных до и результата после... а ещё определения таблиц...